# Pass/Access Object Attributes to/from another Class

Tags: perl

**Issue:** Unable to access parent object attributes

### Verification.pm: (Parent class)

```
package Verification;
use Verification::Proid;

sub Proid
{
    my $self = shift;
    print Dumper($self);
    my $result = Verification::Proid->validate($self);

    return $result; 
}
```

**Dumper result**

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
    'event_name' => 'validate',
    'Verification_Type' => 'Proid',
    'Verification_Value' => 'ecmetric',
    'xml_request' => bless( do{\(my $o = 148410616)}, 'XML::LibXML::Document' ),
    'Verification_Options' => [
                                {
                                '2' => 'UNIX'
                                }
                              ],
    'Verification_ID' => '3'
    }, 'Verification' );
```

---

### Proid.pm: (Child class)

```
package Verification::Proid;
our @ISA = qw(Verification);

sub validate 
{
    my $self = shift;
    print Dumper($self);
    my $result;

    foreach my $validation_type ( @$self->{Verification_Options} )
    {
        do stuff...
    }
}
```

**Dumper result**

```
$VAR1 = 'Verification::Proid';
```

What am I doing wrong that the child class isn't properly getting all the attributes from the object passed to it?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused: who is a parent and who is a child in this object model?

Answer (score 3):

1. your *call syntax* is wrong. `Verification::Proid->validate($self)` is calling a method on the *class*, not on `$self`.
2. The *concept* is wrong. A parent class shouldn't be calling things in child classes by name; it completely defeats the purpose of having classes.
3. Your object doesn't *belong* to the supposed child class; it's blessed into `Verification`, not `Verification::Proid`. If it was actually an instance of `Verification::Proid` you could just call `$self->validate` on it, even from within the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out the flaws @hobbs, pretty obvious I need to read up more about OO Perl...Until I get a better handle on it, I figured out a functional workaround by utilizing Class::Singleton in Verification.pm

**Verification.pm**

```
package Verification;
use Verification::Proid;
use Class::Singleton;

#Instantiate the object as a singleton

sub Proid
{
    return Verification::Proid->validate();
}
```

**Proid.pm**

```
package Verification::Proid;
our @ISA = qw(Verification);

sub validate 
{
    my $self = Verification->instance;
    print Dumper($self);

    foreach my $validation_type ( @{$self->{Verification_Options}} )
    {
        do stuff...
    }
}
```

**Dumper result is what I needed**

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
    'event_name' => 'validate',
    'Verification_Type' => 'Proid',
    'Verification_Value' => 'ecmetric',
    'xml_request' => bless( do{\(my $o = 148410616)}, 'XML::LibXML::Document' ),
    'Verification_Options' => [
                                {
                                '2' => 'UNIX'
                                }
                              ],
    'Verification_ID' => '3'
    }, 'Verification' );
```